# Remove all consecutive repeating lines after a pattern

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with data

```
cell (HB)
input
input
input
Z
output
A
input
cell (BP)
input
input
Z1
output
A1
input
```

I want output as

```
cell (HB)
Z
output
A
input
cell (BP)
Z1
output
A1
input
```

I want to remove all consecutive lines with word `input` present after `cell` line

I tried code

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (!a[$i]++) print($i,FS)}{print("\n")}' file
```

But there is no desired change.

Comment: `with word input present after cell line` your shown samples are showing only cell string is present where we can set/unset variables, is there anything else coming on place of cell string? Why I am asking this is, it will be easier for us then where to start looking for consecutive occurrences of input and which block to neglect, let us know on same, thank you.

Comment: No.. the data only have ```cell``` present and we need to remove all lines with ```input``` repeating after cell

Comment: @NEHACHOUDHARY, ok then you could try my answer once and let me know in its comments section how it goes etc, cheers and keep asking good questions, keep sharing good knowledge on this great site, cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples only, could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

```
awk '
!/input/{
  if(count==1){
    print prev
  }
  count=0
  prev=""
}
/input/{
  count++
  prev=$0
  next
}
1
END{
  if(count==1){
    print prev
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `gnu-awk` you may use `RS` and `RT`:

```sh
awk -v RS='cell [^\n]*\n(input\n)+' '{sub(/\n.+/, "\n", RT); ORS=RT} 1' file

cell (HB)
Z
output
A
input
cell (BP)
Z1
output
A1
input
```

Here:

- `-v RS='cell [^\n]*\n(input\n)+'` sets `RS` to `cell` followed by a space followed by anything until a newline and then multiple lines that have text `input` in it.
- `sub(...)`: Removes removed everything after first newline
- `ORS=RT`: Sets output record separator same as text contained in `RT`
- `1`: Prints each record with `ORS`

Answer (score 1):

Shorter than expected, I wonder if there is something wrong with it:

```
$ awk '!(f&&/input/){print;f=0}/cell/{f=1}' file
```

Output:

```
cell (HB)
Z
output
A
input
cell (BP)
Z1
output
A1
input
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/(cell.*)\n.*input/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Turn on extended regexp by setting `-E`.

Open a two line window.

If the line contains `cell` and then next line contains `input`, remove the last line and repeat.

Otherwise, print/delete the first line and repeat.

---

This generic solution removes duplicate lines all together.

```
sed -E 'N;/^(.*)\n\1$/{:a;s/\n.*//;$!{N;/^(.*)\n\1$/ba};D};P;D' file
```

Turn on extended regexp by setting `-E`.

Open a two line window.

If the lines in the window are duplicate, remove the last line and continue doing so until the two lines are different, then delete the first.

Otherwise, print/delete the first line and repeat.